# Best way to bulk load data in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I need to load 300 million records(each record 60KB) in hazelcast using csv/flat files.What is the best way to load all this data in fastest possible manner?
I can read  record by record and do a map.put in hazelcast. Is there a way to perform multiple writes in one map.put? Or is there any utility which can do this?

Comment: dear user296602. please accept one of the answers if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Chris's comment, you can find an example of async loader / streamer in Hazelcast Simulator code base. This code used to load data to the grid before tests. [AsyncMapStreamer](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-simulator/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/simulator/worker/loadsupport/AsyncMapStreamer.java).
As an option, you can exercise `map.putAll` method. But in this case you need to find optimal batch size of temporary map.

Cheers, 
Vik

Comment: what is the strategy to find optimal batch size?

Comment: @Vik Gamov any updates/improvements  according that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You should use IMap::setAsync or IMap::putAll. Probably the first option is way faster as it is completely async and no value is returned, which optimizes network traffic.

Anyhow the most important factor to speed up is serialization. If you use Java objects you really should think about using DataSerializable to optimize serialization.

Comment: what is the strategy to find optimal batch size?

Comment: Testing, since there are too many factors to "have a common optimal size".